# Is calling `Clear()` necessary in the Dispose() method?

Tags: c#

The following code creates a `ConcurrentDictionary` and it the `Clear()` of the dictionary is called in the `Dispose` method. Is it necessary?

```
class EventAggregator : IEventAggregator
{
    public static IEventAggregator Instance { get; } = new EventAggregator();

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<object>> subscriptions = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<object>>();

    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : IApplicationEvent
    {
        if (subscriptions.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out List<object> subscribers))
        {
            // To Array creates a copy in case someone unsubscribes in their own handler
            foreach (var subscriber in subscribers.ToArray())
            {
                ((Action<T>)subscriber)(message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IApplicationEvent
    {
        var subscribers = subscriptions.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), t => new List<object>());
        lock (subscribers) { subscribers.Add(action); }
    }

    public void Unsubscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IApplicationEvent
    {
        //....
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscriptions.Clear(); // Is this necessary?
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you do not have to help the garbage collector, it doesn't care whether it is cleared or not.  Nor would anybody that uses this code enjoy having to call it, expecting that it can only be safe to do so when there are no subscribers left.  Gets much worse when they don't expect that, now they have a nasty threading race bug.

Comment: What is the expected lifetime of an `EventAggregator` object?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, It will be created when the form/page is opened and disposed when the form/page is closed.

Comment: You'll want to remove the `Dispose` method altogether, I suspect.

Comment: What is the intention of disposing the `EventAggregator`? Do you want to ensure that there are no references that would prevent the `EventAggregator` or other objects from being garbage collected?